# Consumir json desde backend php

Tags: php, ionic2, backend

Estoy continuando un proyecto que comencé en el instituto y me gustaría perfeccionarlo para mi titulación, más que una duda me gustaría recibir sugerencias ya que en primera instancia el proyecto lo desarrollé en laravel y cumple su objetivo, pero ahora me gustaría simplificarlo un poco y crear un backend con php que retorne informacon en json y así poder manejar esa información desde cualquier frontend, pensando en angular para aionic, js puro, etc... lo cual me permitiría una flexibilidad interesante.

El tema es que no tengo experiencia en proyectos reales y no se si esa seria una buena forma de trabajar, esta idea se me ocurrió al utilizar las opciones de reedit con json y me pareció una buena forma de trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tienes un sistema muy grande hay un concepto que se conoce como **"separación de responsabilidades"**, y es eso precisamente que puedas hacer un sistema head-less (es decir, sin vistas con diseño en tu framework de backend) y luego consumirlo con algún otro framework de front-end.

Como un ejercicio de aprendizaje es bueno que lo hagas. Yo empezaría por aquí:

1) Crear un nuevo grupo de Laravel que nos devolviera tus datos pero en JSON.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('/datos', 'DatosController');
});
```

2) Crear una aplicación de front-end puro usando algún framework moderno como Angular o Vue.js.

Con este cambio tu mecanismo de autenticación va a cambiar ya que estarías usando algo que se conoce como **RESTful API** y uno de sus principios es que no deben conservar estado entre cada llamada que hagas (stateless). Es decir en un llamado no puedes guardar datos de sesión; en su lugar, lo que se hace es utilizar un token para validar si el acceso al API es o no autorizado.

Aquí hay un post sencillo de cómo implementar un RESTful API: https://arjunphp.com/create-rest-laravel-framework/

Encontré este artículo muy bueno en español, te pongo la definición que también puedes leer en: http://asiermarques.com/2013/conceptos-sobre-apis-rest/

> ¿Qué es REST?
>
> REST, REpresentational State Transfer, es un tipo de arquitectura de
>   desarrollo web que se apoya totalmente en el estándar HTTP.
>
> REST nos permite crear servicios y aplicaciones que pueden ser usadas
>   por cualquier dispositivo o cliente que entienda HTTP, por lo que es
>   increíblemente más simple y convencional que otras alternativas que se
>   han usado en los últimos diez años como SOAP y XML-RPC.
>
> REST se definió en el 2000 por Roy Fielding, coautor principal también
>   de la especificación HTTP. Podríamos considerar REST como un framework
>   para construir aplicaciones web respetando HTTP.
>
> Por lo tanto REST es el tipo de arquitectura más natural y estándar
>   para crear APIs para servicios orientados a Internet.
>
> Existen tres niveles de calidad a la hora de aplicar REST en el
>   desarrollo de una aplicación web y más concretamente una API que se
>   recogen en un modelo llamado Richardson Maturity Model en honor al
>   tipo que lo estableció, Leonard Richardson padre de la arquitectura
>   orientada a recursos. Estos niveles son:
>
> Uso correcto de URIs Uso correcto de HTTP. Implementar Hypermedia.
>   Además de estas tres reglas, nunca se debe guardar estado en el
>   servidor, toda la información que se requiere para mostrar la
>   información que se solicita debe estar en la consulta por parte del
>   cliente.
>
> Al no guardar estado, REST nos da mucho juego, ya que podemos escalar
>   mejor sin tener que preocuparnos de temas como el almacenamiento de
>   variables de sesión e incluso, podemos jugar con distintas tecnologías
>   para servir determinadas partes o recursos de una misma API.

Si tienes dudas más adelante, mándame un mensaje y te puedo ayudar ya con más calma.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me queda muy bien explicado y a la vez me motiva a seguir con mi idea. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, todo esto del desarrollo web es muy interesante; Angular puede ser una buena opción si tu aplicación es grande (más de 40 componentes de UI). En otro caso tal vez te convenga algo más pequeño como Vue.js